# Writing PDF in C:\ folder

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using .NET 4 on Windows 10.
I have a winform application written in vb.net which converts TIFF into PDF using PDFSharp api.
When I try to save the PDF into the C:\ folder there is no exception raised but nothing is written.
When I check if I have write access permission on folder C:\ , VB.NET tells me I do.
I'm using this chunk of code:

```
Private Function HasFolderWriteAccess(path As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Using inputstreamreader As New StreamReader(path)
            inputstreamreader.Close()
        End Using
        Using inputStream As FileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            inputStream.Close()
            Return True
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

When I try to write a file using a StreamWriter, I face the same behavior:

```
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test2.txt"
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
    objWriter.Write("Some text....")
    objWriter.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Text written to file")
```

Is there some kind of magic happening in the Windows 10 C:\ folder that I don't know ?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: `C:\test2.txt`: isn't that `C:<TAB>est2.txt` ?

Comment: It hasn't been allowed to write to the drive's root folder without having admin privileges since Windows Vista (actually, since XP if you were not running as a power user). It's been more than a decade now; it's time you learn how UAC and privileges work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It would be in C/C++. Not VB.Net.

Comment: But what is a good way to check folder write access then?
vb.net tells me c:\ is writable but in practice it isn't

Comment: I'm not sure about Windows 10, but look in this folder instead:  `C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\VirtualStore` and see if your file is there.  Windows doesn't allow writing of files to certain folders and silently redirects them to the virtual store.  Also check [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927387)

Comment: This is it, files are redirected to this directory. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Dunaway's answer (in the comments) is right:

...look in this folder instead: C:\Users\User_name\‌​AppData\Local\Virtual‌​Store and see if your file is there. Windows doesn't allow writing of files to certain folders and silently redirects them to the virtual store...